# How to use sed or awk or grep to find an email in a file that starts with the word "abuse"?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Ubuntu 16.04
GNU bash, version 4.4.0

I need to extract the email in a file that starts with the word  **abuse** .
Here is a file that contains the whois information for an ip address and has the email **abuse@web.ad.jp** inside of it.

```
% [whois.apnic.net]
% Whois data copyright terms    http://www.apnic.net/db/dbcopyright.html

% Information related to '121.92.0.0 - 121.93.255.255'

% Abuse contact for '121.92.0.0 - 121.93.255.255' is 'hostmaster@nic.ad.jp'

inetnum:        121.92.0.0 - 121.93.255.255
netname:        InfoWeb
descr:          FUJITSU LIMITED
descr:          17-25, SHINKAMATA 1-CHOME, OTA-KU,
descr:          TOKYO 144-8588, JAPAN
country:        JP
admin-c:        JNIC1-AP
tech-c:         JNIC1-AP
status:         ALLOCATED PORTABLE
remarks:        Email address for spam or abuse complaints abuse@web.ad.jp
mnt-by:         MAINT-JPNIC
mnt-irt:        IRT-JPNIC-JP
mnt-lower:      MAINT-JPNIC
last-modified:  2015-12-01T22:23:26Z
source:         APNIC

irt:            IRT-JPNIC-JP
address:        Urbannet-Kanda Bldg 4F, 3-6-2 Uchi-Kanda
address:        Chiyoda-ku, Tokyo 101-0047, Japan
e-mail:         hostmaster@nic.ad.jp
abuse-mailbox:  hostmaster@nic.ad.jp
admin-c:        JNIC1-AP
tech-c:         JNIC1-AP
auth:           # Filtered
mnt-by:         MAINT-JPNIC
last-modified:  2017-10-18T10:21:54Z
source:         APNIC
```

I am not concerned about which command extracts the email address of abuse@web.ad.jp  from the file, I'm only concerned that it does it efficiently.

In the past I have used grep to find all email addresses within a file like ...

`grep -o '[[:alnum:]+\.\_\-]*@[[:alnum:]+\.\_\-]*' "$1" | sort | uniq -i`

But never an email that starts with a word, so my expected output from the command would yield me **abuse@web.ad.jp**.

Comment: @Curious Sam, please do add your efforts what you have to solve the problem too in your post and let us know then.

Comment: `grep -o abuse@.* <filename>`

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I normally do and I was in the middle of editing my OP to include a grep command I have used in the past to find all email addresses, then the misses came home and decided to tell me how horrible her work night was. It happens and my apologies there.

Comment: @devd Your reply gave me exactly what I needed and worked perfectly but what is the period for?

Comment: @CuriousSam, please post your expected output in your post and let us know then?>

Comment: Please let us Google that for you: [sed or awk match email address](https://www.google.com/search?q=sed+or+awk+match+email+address).

Comment: Whois records are not standardized. A single regex will work fabulously on some records and not at all on others. Perhaps you will want to study the various existing whois parsers, but none of them are anywhere near perfect. For a start, you should understand the hiesarchy in records which contain multiple different abuse addresses.

Comment: @Triplee You posted great information. I have a few weeks of reading and finetuning my script and I'll definitely research your reply.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I have done so.

Comment: You can use `grep -m 1 -oE 'abuse@[^[:blank:]]+' file`

Comment: @anubhava combining your ```grep``` suggestion and @devd suggestion from below, I come up with a few more. ```grep -i -o 'abuse[a-z0-9]*@[^[:blank:]]+' <filename>``` or ```grep -m 1 -oE  'abuse[a-z0-9]*@[a-z\.]\+' <filename>```

Comment: You don't even need `[a-z0-9]*` here, just `grep -m 1 -ioE 'abuse@[^[:blank:]]+' file` is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ grep "abuse[a-z]*@[a-z\.]\+" -o <filename>
```

Works assuming your e-mail doesn't include numbers or capitalized letters.

Comment: What if the email id is like `abuse23`?
This would be useful for all:
 `grep -i -o 'abuse[a-z0-9]*@[a-z\.]\+' <filename>`

Comment: @devd I saw a few Russian abuse emails enclosed with single quotes that by-passed your latest reply. If you have a moment to show how to include that, that would be great.

Comment: @CuriousSam This might help `grep -i -o "abuse\('\)\?[a-z0-9]*\('\)\?@[a-z\.]\+" <filename>`. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: @devd Right on!!